# Jersey Use Jackson or Jettison for JSONConfiguration.natural().build()

Tags: jersey, jackson, jax-rs, portability, jettison

I am trying to portable rest application for Weblogic and Jboss. Currently we are using jersey for rest app. with portable implementation jboss will use resteasy.

Context: in our app we are `@Provider` class using `ContextResolver<JAXBContext>` return `JSONJAXBContext` with `JSONConfiguration.natural().build()`. so i am trying to find jersey internally used above configuration for Jackson or Jettison. please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider forgetting anything to do with Jersey, if you're looking for portability. You can simply use the [jackson-jaxrs-json-provider](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers). If you are allowing for resource/providers to be auto-discovered, then there should be no extra configuration for this provider needed.

If you are registering resources/providers explicitly, then you should register either `JacksonJsonProvider` or `JacksonJsonJaxbProvider` (if you need JAXB annotation support). If you are using auto-registration (scanning), then as stated earlier, these providers will be be implicitly registered for you.

As for the `ContentResolver`, if you need to configure the marshaller/unmarshaller, the you should use the Jackson's `ObjectMapper` (e.g. `implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>`). There are many different configurations for the `ObjectMapper`

- [See the Jackson Documentation for more information](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDocumentation)